# Download instead of load url in WebView when url contains x

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-download-manager

I have an Android app that is pretty much a WebView containing a mobile website. I have minimum control over the code of the website but can inject javascript.

The website contains download links to PDF, DOC, ZIP etc. files, with most of them only accessible if the user is logged in. At first I simply made the app open links containing "FileHandler.axd" (the script that handles files) in the normal browser, but if users are not logged in through the app ánd browser they'll just get an error.

So now I'm trying to make the app use the download manager if a link is tapped but am having some trouble as it's not really working at all. I don't have a lot of experience developing Android apps so any lead on where I'm doing it wrong would be greatly appreciated.

These are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I marked the code I added last with a "DOWNLOAD MANAGER CODE BELOW" comment block.

This is part of my MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        // Get current UserAgent
        String curua = mWebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
        // Add -comapp string to useragent for detection
        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(curua + "-comapp");

        // Use remote resource
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.onsplatform.tv/comapp");

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        /////////////////////////////////
        // DOWNLOAD MANAGER CODE BELOW //
        /////////////////////////////////
       
        if(mWebView.getUrl().contains("FileHandler.axd")){
            String url = mWebView.getUrl();
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
            // You can change the name of the downloads, by changing "download" to everything you want, such as the mWebview title...
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }

    } else {
        //no connection
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "geen internet / no internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

---

## Edit

I'm getting a feeling I put the code in the wrong place. I'm guessing I need a `public method` for the `WebViewClient`? But which one, `onLoadResource()`? I've been reading the documentation but I don't really know if I'm looking at the right stuff.

I'm guessing there's a sort of event handler that fires when a link is loading, maybe being able to intercept that, start the download manager for that url and prevent the url from loading in the webview?

I have a class that extends WebViewClient, I'm guessing that would be the place:

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("onsplatform.tv")) { // && !url.toLowerCase().contains("filehandler")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```